# Homomorphism of $: \mathbb{Q}^{*}/⟨-1⟩\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^+$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, rational-numbers, group-homomorphism

There is a definition from Group Theory about isomorphisms and homomorphisms. For example, if $G$ and $H$ are groups and $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, it must satisfy that $\forall x,y \in G$, then $\varphi (xy) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y)$. Isomorphism is just a bijection and a homomorphism.

Now, when talking about normal subgroups, it is defined as follows:

> Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff for all $g \in G$, $gHg^{-1} = H$, and it is denoted as $H \trianglelefteq G$.

I got this definition from [Normal Subgroup](https://brilliant.org/wiki/normal-subgroup) (paraphrased).

Now, my question is: Is there any construction of a homomorphism $: \mathbb{Q}^{\times}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{+}$? Can you give an example?

I already proved that $\langle -1 \rangle = \{1, -1\}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ (group of rational numbers under multiplication). Also, I know there are many methods for proving these things, such as the *Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem*. Normally, to demonstrate that $G/H \cong K$, prove that $\varphi: G \rightarrow K$ is a homomorphism, it is surjective, and that the $\ker(\varphi) = H$, for some group $H$ (this is the one I want to use). However, I've been trying to work on this, and I couldn't construct any homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$. I have some knowledge about this topic, but not so much. Any hints will help.

#### Edit (11/6/2021): Making my question clearer

To make the question clear, I want to prove the isomorphism of $$\varphi: \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{+}$$

I needed a closed formula for homomorphism of $\varphi$, which was complicated to find, so I needed some help with this.

#### Edit 2 (11/6/2021): Finding my mistake

I finally found my mistake! I thought that $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ and $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ were the same group under the same operation! Thanks to Thomas Andrews, Arturo Margidin, and Greg Martin for helping out on this problem!

Comment: You’ve got the triangle backward. It should be $H \trianglelefteq G.$ That’s `\trianglelefteq`

Comment: $\phi(q)=|q|$ is such a homomorphism.

Comment: Thank You, @ThomasAndrews!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, but if that's true, shouldn't $\varphi (1) = 0$??

Comment: $\mathbb Q^+$ means the positive rationals, and that is only a group under multiplication, not addition. If you mean the group $(\mathbb Q,+)$ of all rationals under addition, then you should edit the question.

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasAndrews, again! Now I edited the post.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^*/\langle -1\rangle$ is free abelian, so there are uncountably many such homomorphisms. Basically, just decide what you want to happen to the primes, and extend.

Comment: The title and various parts of the question send mixed messages about just what your question is. It's not the case that $\mathbb{Q}^{*}/⟨-1⟩$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ are isomorphic, so while there are lots of homomorphisms (there's always at least one homorphism from any group to any other group), there are no isomorphisms.

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz you need to fix the title, too.

Comment: There is no isomorphism $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\times)\to (\mathbb{Q},+)$, let alone "the" (as if there were one and exactly one). The domain has elements of order $2$, the codomain does not. Even moding out by $\{-1,1\}$ you cannot get injective morphisms from $(\mathbb{Q}^*)/\{-1,1\}$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$. There are **lots** of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}^*$ (in fact, uncountably many), but they all have kernels that properly contain $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: **Do not delete**. Deleting demonstrates utter disregard for the time and effort people put into trying to help you. If you do that, please make sure never to expect any help from me, at the very least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\phi:\mathbb Q^\times\to (\mathbb Q,+)$ is a homomorphism with kernel $\{1,-1\},$ then let $\frac pq=\phi(2)$ and $\frac rs=\phi(3),$ with $p,q,r,s\in \mathbb Z, q,s\neq 0.$

If $p=0$ or $r=0,$ then either $2$ or $3$ is in the kernel, so $\ker \phi\neq \{ 1,-1\}.$

So $p,q,r,s\neq 0.$

Let $x=2^{qr}3^{-sp}.$ Then $$\phi(x)=qr\cdot\frac pq+(-sp)\cdot\frac rs=0,$$ So $x\in\ker\phi.$

Show $2^{qr}3^{-sp}\neq \pm 1$ when $p,q,r,s$ are non-zero integers.

Comment: What does this mean, though? Does it mean that I can't construct any homomorphism for $\varphi$ such that there is an isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Q}, +)$ because there is no homomorphism? This answer is not very clear.

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz The answer shows that there is no homomorphism  $\phi\colon\mathbb{Q}^*\to (\mathbb{Q},+)$ whose kernel is *precisely* $\{-1,1\}$. It is quite clear. Unfortunately, *your question* continues to be unclear, since you still have "isomorphism" in the subject line, you talk about homomorphisms in the post, and you never clarify exactly what you want or are asking for.